# HighChart bubble type. datalabel text overflow form the plotOptions area

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

here's the demo : [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118)

[image]

the datalabel is too long to display , i want it just inside the bubble and the overflowed text displayed as "ACDE..."

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two solutions for this case.

- set the overflow to ellipsis and set some width for the dataLabel:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ye5s7m6g/1/

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: "{point.name}",
          style: {
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
          width: 45
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.dataLabels.style

- enable textPath feature in the dataLabels:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0srgnvxd/1/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: "{point.name}",
                textPath: {
            enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.dataLabels.textPath.enabled

Comment: thanks for your answer, textPath maybe not meet the UI design, and for ellipsis approche, it works but I want the width can be responsive to the bubble's width. I tried `width:50%`. but it's the 50% of its self not the bubble

Comment: Here is a function which calculates each bubble width, set this width for the dataLabel and next translate it to the middle of the bubble, but only once- after the first render, later this will be done automatically after each resize. 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y2t6se1b/

Comment: thanks for you answer @Sebastian , it works great. but I use react-highchart-official lib , can you please tell me how to bind the render() method in react component(funcation component)? you can modify my demo :https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118-6vef8y

Comment: There you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118-wufufc?file=chartConfig.js